# YQL XSLT implementation limitations

Tags: xslt, yql

For some reason, YQL's XSLT table can't parse my stylesheet. I have used the stylesheet successfully with the W3C's XSLT service. Here's an example of the problem in [YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20xslt%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Frobartsd.freehostia.com%2Ffiles%2FYQL-KIM2.xml%22%20and%20stylesheet%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Frobartsd.freehostia.com%2Ffiles%2FYQL-KIM.xslt%22). Why does this not work in YQL?

Also, I have yet to figure out how to pass the results of a YQL query to the XSLT table as the XML to be transformed while also specifying a stylesheet url. Current workaround is to abuse the W3C's service.

Comment: It's not good practice to link to big source in other place. You should built a reduce input sample

Comment: I've trimmed the sample XML file that I am processing.

Comment: Before getting the XSLT working, I tried retrieving YQL results with the XML table via the rest URL which didn't work, but the XSLT had no problem using YQL results as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stylesheet is defined as 1.0 but you're using `replace()` and `tokenize()` which is part of the 2.0 standard. However it is a fully valid XSLT/XPath 2.0 stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks. It was unclear in the XPath function documentation that these are 2.0 functions. I've tried changing the declaration, but YQL still does not like it. I guess their implementation is 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Per T answer, change this:

```
<xsl:variable name="r">
<xsl:value-of select="replace(tr/td/p/a/following-sibling::text(),
                              '\s*-\s*(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\s*',
                              '$1,$2,$3')" />
</xsl:variable>
```

With this:

```
<xsl:variable name="r" 
        select="translate(tr/td/p/a/following-sibling::text(),'. -',',')">
```

These:

```
tokenize($r,',')[1]

tokenize($r,',')[2]

tokenize($r,',')[3]
```

With these:

```
substring-before($r,',')

substring-before(substring-after($r,','),',')

substring-after(substring-after($r,','),',')
```

**Note**: This is just in case you don't know the amount of digit in advance, otherwise you could do:

```
substring($r,1,2)

substring($r,4,2)

substring($r,7)
```

Also, this

```
replace(tr/td/p[@class='t11bold']/a,'\s+',' ')
```

It should be just this:

```
normalize-space(tr/td/p[@class='t11bold']/a)
```

And finaly this:

```
replace($d,'^[^\[]*\[\s*(\d+:\d{2})?\s*-?\s*([^\]]*)\]\s*$','$2')
```

Could be:

```
normalize-space(substring-after(substring-before(substring-after($d,'['),']'),'-'))
```

Comment: Thanks, normalize-space function should help avoid reliance on XPATH 2.0 regular expressions. The values could be 2 digits, so I do need the substring-before & -after solution.

Comment: Your suggestions were very helpful in rewriting the stylesheet to 1.0.